# How to exclude app settings from a docker image (and add them to the container)?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, configuration

I have built my ASP.NET Core website, I can deploy it into a docker image and run it as a container. Everything is hunky dory until I want to move it to our public server that has different configuration settings, like db connection string.

**The config files (appsettings.json) are baked inside the image.** Is there a way to exclude them from the image and mount them to their appropriate directory when I start the container?

Comment: Two basic approaches: Make them controllable by environment variable or mount the config file as a volume from the host into the container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I provide application config to my .NET Core Web API services running in docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197493/how-can-i-provide-application-config-to-my-net-core-web-api-services-running-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the default appsettings.json baked inside the image. The default settings can be used for local development.

Once you move to a another environment, you can mount the appropriate setting file onto the container using the -v option

```
docker run -v <path-to-appsettings.json-on-host>:<path-to-appsettings.json-inside-container> <container-name>
```

Comment: Can you really map a single file like that? Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @flipdoubt Single-file mounts work on Docker for Linux (and Mac) but not on Docker for Windows, with the latter supporting directory mounts only.