# File storage options with Docker

Tags: docker

We plan to use Docker with our new asp.net core project and one of the requirements is that app will upload files and we need to have them stored permanently.
We have read that Docker creates filesystem/volumes (i might be imprecise in terminology here) per container and if container is recreated for whatever reason - filesystem/volume exposed to container is lost.

We would like to avoid storing files in our database (mongodb).

What is the usual, best practice way to have files permanently&reliably stored with Docker?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping non-ephemeral data in external storage servers is one solution.  An more recent approach is to use S3 or a local equivalent like [minio](https://minio.io/) to store shared or private data that needs to outlive the lifetime of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197493/how-can-i-provide-application-config-to-my-net-core-web-api-services-running-in/42335351#42335351)

It's possible to create data volumes in the docker image/container.

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

This will create a new volume inside a container at /webapp. But the files stored will be lost once the container is destroyed.

On the other hand, we can mount a host directory into a container. The host directory will then by accessible inside the container.

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

This command mounts the host directory, /src/webapp, into the container at /webapp. 
The files stored by the docker container into this mounted directory will be available even if the container is destroyed. If you are planning to persist the files beyond the life time of container this will be a good option.

Comment: yes that looks like an option because yes, we definitely need to persist beyond the lifetime of a container. let me just ask, is that a usual was to do persistance for these kind of cases? are there any negatives if going that way? thanks!